# jQuery, hide and show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some content/Text that is now showing and hiding on a button click, the content is hidden first then shows on a click and hides on click.

I am trying to get only half of the text hidden instead, and show it on a click, also hide the half on a click instead of hiding the whole text and showing the whole text.

This code is working fine but hiding/showing the whole content.

I am new to jQuery :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // Hide the div
   jQuery('#reveal').hide();
   jQuery('.rv_button').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     jQuery("#reveal").slideToggle();
     jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
   });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add you html  ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Use the `<>` button in the editor to create a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the whole text as in `var` then you will be able to cut from it as you want by `slice` function ,

then you will be able to add the `whole text` or `sliced text`

```js
    $(function(){
    $("p").each(function(){
        var wholeTxt = $(this).text();
      var cuttedText = wholeTxt.slice(0, 25); // you can add as you want 
      $(this).text(cuttedText);
      $(this).click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("opend")){
          $(this).addClass("opend");
          $(this).text(wholeTxt);
        }else {
          $(this).removeClass("opend");
          $(this).text(cuttedText);
        }
      })
    })
    
      
    })
```

```css
p {
  cursor : pointer
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <p id="reveal">

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </p>

<p> hello world hello world hello world hello world </p>

<p> hello world 2 hello world 2 hello world 2 hello world 2</p>

<p> hello world 3 hello world 3 hello world 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```